# How can I run my debugger in VSCode when I get a prompt that I am missing the build/debug/outDebug in my folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Disclaimer: I am a novice, so there is a slight (read: HUGE!) chance that I am not asking the right questions, but here is what I could make of it so far:

I have been trying to run the Debugger  on a C program (after installing it via MinGW), so then I run the C++(GDB/LLDB), but I get an error indicating that I am missing the build/debug/outDebug program in my initial folder and VSCode prompts me to open the launch.json file.

Then I saved this json file with the right address in my folder, and I realize that this is pbb the file that is meant to create my build/debug/outDebug. How does this work?

[Debug launch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQGv.jpg)

[The json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxvAM.jpg)

I checked again and the MinGW is installed with the appropriate options on my computer, I am able to run the program and it works correctly, but the Debugger returns no output in the Terminal (but does return the error described above)